# How to write Django logs on Heroku to an external file?

Tags: python, django, logging, heroku, amazon-web-services

I need to log all the requests/responses to use them for further analysis. Heroku is an ephermal system, so I need to write the logs directly to AWS(I am using s3boto to read and write media files on AWS).I have not been able to achieve that using python's logging module and RotatingFileHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Heroku's standard [log service](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging).  Just log to stdout.  It aggregates it all for you, across all your dynos.  You can then use any of the [log add-ons](https://addons.heroku.com/#logging) to persist/search etc.

Comment: I am already doing it the way you suggested. The issue is that it logs everything then. I have to manually filter the results as I need some specific logs.